# Compatible types in functions

Tags: typescript

Let say we have this code:

```
class MyEvent {
    timestamp:number;
}
class AEvent extends MyEvent{
    x:number;
    y:number;   
}
class BEvent extends MyEvent{
    key:string; 
}
var fn:(event:MyEvent)=>void;
function AE(event:AEvent){
    let x = event.x; //Ok, but BEvent hasn't 'x' property. 
}
fn = AE;
fn(new BEvent());
```

Typescript doesn't inform about error. For typescript it is a valid code.
I have tried it in typescript playground. (1.8 version)

How do I enforce typescript to forbid it?

For example, in C++

```
class Base {
    public:
        int timestamp;
};

class B: public Base {
    public:
        char key; 
};
class A: public Base {
    public:
        int x;
        int y;
};


void fA(A *ptr) {}

void (*fn)(Base *ptr);


int main()
{
    A *a = new A();
    B *b = new B();

    fn = fA; //error: invalid conversion from 'void (*)(A*)' to 'void (*)(Base*)' 
    fn(b);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The function parameters are bivariant to allow common javascript patterns even if some runtime error can occur in some rare case.

According to type [compatibility handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) :

> When comparing the types of function parameters, assignment succeeds
>   if either the source parameter is assignable to the target parameter,
>   or vice versa. This is unsound because a caller might end up being
>   given a function that takes a more specialized type, but invokes the
>   function with a less specialized type. In practice, this sort of error
>   is rare, and allowing this enables many common JavaScript patterns.

[Why are function parameters bivariant?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-function-parameters-bivariant)

> In summary, in the TypeScript type system, the question of whether a
>   more-specific-type-accepting function should be assignable to a
>   function accepting a less-specific type provides a prerequisite answer
>   to whether an array of that more specific type should be assignable to
>   an array of a less specific type. Having the latter not be the case
>   would not be an acceptable type system in the vast majority of cases,
>   so we have to take a correctness trade-off for the specific case of
>   function argument types.

Comment: Good answer. I concluded that my case is 'some runtime error can occur in some rare case.'