# Why are first class functions not type checked in typescript?

Tags: generics, typescript, functional-programming

In the example below, the `Promise::then` visitor function `f` has an expectation of receiving an `Example`.  If I explicitly pass in a malformed object with missing properties, I get a type error.

But if I simply pass the function `f` to `.then(f)` I get no type error, even though typescript knows the type of the `T` in `Promise<T>` is not an `Example`.

```
interface Example {
    id: number
    age: number
}

interface Promise <T> {
    then <U> ( f: ( a: T) => U ) : Promise<U> 
}

function f(s:Example){
    return s.age
}

var p : Promise<{ id: number }>

p.then(f) // no type error (bad)

p.then(function(a){
    f(a) // type error (good)
})
```

I'm wondering why this happens but also, techniques to mitigate permissive type checking in Typescript.

If bivariance explains this phenomenon, then why is there a type error when `f` is explicitly applied?  Why are their different rules for 1st class functions vs explicit application?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38699449/compatible-types-in-functions/38700451#38700451. See also [Type-checking unsoundness: standardize treatment of such issues among TypeScript team/community?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9825)

Comment: @artem I don't think this is caused by bivariance.  But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I think is happening:

> ```
> p.then(f) // no type error (bad)
> ```

- `T` here is `{ id: number }`
- `then()` is declared to take argument of type `{id: number} => U`
- f has type `Example => number`
- `Example` is assignable to `{id: number}`, so `f` is compatible with argument type of `then()` due to [bivariance](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance)

Let me add one more example:

```
p.then(function(a : Example){
    f(a)
})
```

It also compiles without errors, for the same reason:

- argument for `then()` has type `Example => number`

Now, why does the following not compile?

> ```
> p.then(function(a){
>     f(a) // type error (good)
> })
> ```

- I guess that `a` is deduced to have type `{id: number}` (because the simplest thing to do is to take it to be `T` from the declaration of `p`)
- so `f` is called with incompatible argument here
- because `{id: number}` is not assignable to `Example` that `f` needs (age is missing).

Notice that the error is not about argument for then(), but about argument for f().

Now, for the second part of the question:

> techniques to mitigate permissive type checking in Typescript.

If you need correct type checking, IMO Typescript is not an option as long as unsound but "usable" typechecking remains one of its explicit design goals. I've heard that Scala, Haskell and OCaml all have compilers targeting javacsript nowadays (but I have no idea how usable they are).

And the third part of the question:

> Why are their different rules for 1st class functions vs explicit
>   application?

Because in the first case the argument is a function, and in the second case (which does not compile) the argument has deduced type `{id : number`}, which is not a function. Bivariance is an ad-hoc rule that applies only when it needs to be decided if one function type is compatible with another function type. The first case compiles because once it sees that `then()` argument is OK according to the rules, it does not descend into `then()` implementation to check how it will actually work there. That's what makes it unsound.

Comment: Your answer is helpful but I still don't understand why bivariance is more permissive specifically for 1st class functions.  If bivariance explains this phenomenon then there should be no type error for the explicit application, the same rules should apply.

Is the issue Typescript's generics are unable to infer the structure when it is a 1st class function?

Comment: I added another part of the answer trying to explain it. The error is caused by incorrect argument type for an argument which is not a function, so bivariance does not apply.